# Failed to start slapd in CentOS

Tags: centos, ldap

I was trying to setup an LDAP server for my development. For this purpose, I have chose CentOS 6.3 install it in VirtualBox host in Fedora 17. I'm following [this tutorial](http://wiki.openiam.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7635198) to guide me on this setup, anyhow when I start the service using this command `service slapd start`, I got this error:

```
Checking configuration files for slapd:   [FAILED]
/etc/openldap/slapd.conf: line 9: bad config line.
slaptest: bad configuration file!
```

I'm sure I have this file `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf` to the owner of ldap. May I know any idea to rectified this problem?

**UPDATE**

I have extract the first few lines of text from `slapd.conf`, looking at `line 9`, that is an empty line.

```
#
# See slapd.conf(5) for details on configuration options.
# This file should NOT be world readable.
#
include     /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

# Added for policy
include /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema

# Allow LDAPv2 client connections.  This is NOT the default.
allow bind_v2

# Do not enable referrals until AFTER you have a working directory
# service AND an understanding of referrals.
#referral   ldap://root.openldap.org

pidfile     /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
```

Comment: maybe first check out what the line 9 on the config says... `vi /etc/openldap/slapd.conf` then `:9` .

Comment: I have check on that file, but it is an empty line there. Any clue on this?

Comment: It may not be the answer to your question, but have you tried Apache Directory studio? It comes with an integrated LDAP server and with a cool GUI LDAP editor which i found perfect for quick LDAP development: http://directory.apache.org/studio/

Comment: if line 9 is empty maybe the problem is on line 8: `/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema` what about this schema?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the blank lines in your `slapd.conf` file; that fixed it for me.

Comment: I removed the blank space but still the same problum..

Comment: You have to remove **all** the blank lines.  Did you do that?

Comment: Ensure that there are no trailing whitespaces.